# Кто-нибудь знает, как сделать аналог AppContext.SetSwitch на .net 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Необходимо изменить значение конфигурации программы:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures", false);
```

В .NET Framework 4.6 всё срабатывает замечательно, а в более старых версиях нужно редактировать, а потом носить с приложением app.config. Вопрос к профессионалам: кто-нибудь знает аналоги, либо способ переноса этого метода из 4.6?

Прошу не предлагать способы с изменением реестра, склейкой конфига с приложением и уж тем более с апгрейдом до 4.6.

Comment: .NET является в 99% случаев (по моему мнению) обверткой над WINAPI, опишите что эта строка делает, думаю в MSDN можно найти как это делается на WINAPI, либо дизассемблером idlasm/dotPeek  открыть dll и глянуть что метод SetSwitch делает.

Comment: Эта строка изменяет конфиг приложения во время выполнения, добавляет туда `<Switch.UseLegacyAccessibilityFeatures enabled="false" />`

Comment: Я уже глядел mscorlib, попытался перенести класс в свою программу, только метод ничего не сделал.

Comment: Альтернативный вопрос, что именно выключает данный выключатель? Может это можно выключить другим способом?

Comment: Судя по МСДН, все эти настройки просто не работают в 4.5, читайте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility там всё о версиях выше

Comment: А как именно целевая библиотека получает значение этой настройки (судя по описанию она умеет её делать под 4.5)? Может целевую библиотеку рефлексией дергнуть?

Comment: Я думаю, что путём некоторых манипуляций можно заставить программу съедать значение этой настройки конфига.

Comment: Целевая библиотека похоже что `System.Windows.Forms.dll` поля приватного класса `System.AccessibilityImprovements` думаю это оно.

Comment: Я проверил его значение - там стоит 0. На что надо поменять?

Comment: Там два свойства Level1 и Level2. Через них идет обращение. Надо посмотреть что они возвращают... Если есть конфиг - то они читают с конфига, а если нету... надо смотреть...